# actionscript Blinking tooltip when addChild(textfield);

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is piece of class which called right after i already drawn some objects in it, problem is when i have sprite.addChild(textfield) included it starting to blink alot.

```
       addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
       addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutHandler);
       addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);

      }



            private function mouseOverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
                //creating a new tooltip instance
                var tooltip:Sprite = new Sprite();
                /*//we tell the holder to hold our tooltip
       holder = tooltip;
       //adding text to the tooltip
       //tooltip.myText = "ASS";
       //positioning the tooltip on the stage
       holder.x = stage.mouseX;
       holder.y = stage.mouseY - 15;
       //adding the tooltip to the stage*/
                textfield.selectable = false;
       textformat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
       textformat.size = 12;
       textformat.color = 0x000000;
       textfield.defaultTextFormat = textformat;
       textfield.x = x;
       textfield.y = y;
       textfield.width = width;
       textfield.height = height;
       textfield.text = myName;
       sprite.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x00BB00);
       sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1);
       sprite.graphics.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
       sprite.graphics.endFill();
       sprite.addChild(textfield);
       sprite.x = stage.mouseX;
       sprite.y = stage.mouseY - 15;
       tooltip.addChild(sprite);
                //holder.addChild(tooltip);
       addChild(sprite)
      }

            private function mouseOutHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
                //we remove the holder when the cursor is outside our button
       removeChild(sprite);
      }

            //we create this function to move the tooltip everytime the cursor is moved
            private function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
       sprite.x = stage.mouseX;
       sprite.y = stage.mouseY - 15;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i'm not sure about that, this might explain your problem. You can give more information for better solution.

"when you add sprite, it calls mouseOutHandler, cause you add your sprite under your cursor. And you remove the sprite with //removeChild(sprite); and mouseOverHandler calls again. And it goes like that."

Comment: already fixed it. Actually add and remove is not very correct since i'm doing entire tooltip routine inside class. I basically replaced addchild/removechild with sprite.visible true/false